# Getting The Multi Value dictketError when passing data through URL in Django contains spaces

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is the my Django URL looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewpro.html?d=5%20STAR.`
But my passing data like `d =5 STAR`.
But my problem is when using    `pname=request.GET['d']`, it shows `multivalueDictKeyError` and i can't bind the data in the variable. Can u please help me to solve it....

```
This is my viewpro.html page.

 <table class="content" border="2px">
```

```
<th>S-No</th>
<th>P-id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Productname</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Ordertime</th>
<th>Orderstatus</th>
<th>Actions</th>


</tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in result %}
  <tr align="center">    
    <td>{{ forloop.counter}}</td>
    <td>{{ row.0}}</td>
    <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.4 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.5 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.6 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.7 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.8 }}</td>
    <td><a href="/acceptorder.html?d={{row.0}}?d2={{row.4}}?d3={{row.5}}?d4={{row.6}}"><input type="button" value="Accept"></a>  <a href="/rejectorder.html?d={{row.0}}"><input type="button" value="Reject" style="background-color : red"></a></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody> 
</table>
```

And my view.py is

```
def acceptorder(request):
    pid = request.GET.get('d')
    productname = request.GET.get('d2')
    quantity = request.GET.get('d3')
    price = request.GET.get('d4')
    print(productname)
```

when printing productname the error is occured.

my urls.py there is no passing parameters in that

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('product.html/', views.product, name='product'),
    path('productorder.html/', views.productorder, name='productorder'),
    path('orderpage.html/', views.orderpage, name='orderpage'),  
    path('order.html/', views.order, name='order'), 
    path('about.html/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('admin.html/', views.admin, name='admin'),
    path('login.html/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('purchase.html/', views.purchase, name='purchase'),
    path('logout.html/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('logincheck.html/', views.logincheck, name='logincheck'),
    path('adminpage.html/', views.adminpage, name='adminpage'),
    path('admincheck.html/', views.admincheck, name='admincheck'),
    path('viewpro.html/', views.viewpro, name='viewpro'),
    path('acceptorder.html/', views.acceptorder, name='acceptorder'),
    path('rejectorder.html/', views.rejectorder, name='rejectorder'),
    path('manages.html/', views.manages, name='manages'),
    path('viewdata.html/', views.viewdata, name='viewdata'),
    path('addproduct.html/', views.addproduct, name='addproduct'),
    path('viewuserdata.html/', views.viewuserdata, name='viewuserdata'),
    path('viewuserdata1.html/', views.viewuserdata1, name='viewuserdata1'),
    path('addproducts.html/', views.addproducts, name='addproducts'),
    path('deleteproduct.html/', views.deleteproduct, name='deleteproduct'),
    path('stock.html/', views.stock, name='stock'),
    path('stockadd.html/', views.stockadd, name='stockadd'),
    path('stockview.html/', views.stockview, name='stockview'),
]
```

Comment: can you please provide some stuff so people easy to understand why this happen

Comment: Show us your related ```views.py```, ```urls.py``` at least.

Comment: Actually i got this 5 STAR data from the table.Basically it contains space between them(not _ ).So for further page processing i need this value. So i pass this value through the url with variable name d. But after at request.GET['d] it shows the MultiValueDictKeyError and could not save the value in variable. The URL have a %20 between 5 and STAR.@l.b.vasoya

Comment: Show us your views and urls. Plz edit your question to get help!!! It is as simple as that

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane my question is updated sir

Comment: @l.b.vasoya The post is edited sir

Comment: replace this url to your accept url `<a href="{% url 'acceptorder' %}?d={{row.0}}?d2={{row.4}}?d3={{row.5}}?d4={{row.6}}">`

Comment: @l.b.vasoya i need to replace the %20 in my request.GET sir. The answer you are given is not resolved my issue. MultiValueDictKeyError at /acceptorder.html/
'd2'. This is what i got sir.

Comment: brother this passing way is totaly wrong you should use form so you can not this type of problem ahead django provide better way to use url take my suggestion check this using form and url `simpleisbetterthen` site may helpfull to you because might be you doing not proper way to passing data on view so take some time see may i helpfull you?

Comment: @l.b.vasoya But with this i need to change my entire code into object oriented type. In my project i did not used that way. So please show me another way to get rid of that